# getReadableDatabase() Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am entering some data into this database and then trying to display that data, but I get a `Null Pointer Exception at getReadableDatabase()`. The main activity from where I enter data is as follows:

```
public class TabListData extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.employeeslist);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);

        String nam = name.getText().toString();
        String mob = mobile.getText().toString();

        Button b = (Button) v;
        Button b1 = (Button) v;
         Database d = new Database(getBaseContext());

         switch (b.getId()) {
         case R.id.enter:
             d.input(nam, mob);
         case R.id.employeeslist:
            /* ArrayList<EmployeesResult> results = d.selectEmployees();
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "# records: "
                        + results.size(), 1000);
                t.show();*/
             Intent i = new Intent(this, EmployeesList.class);
            // i.putExtra("Name", "Name");
             startActivity(i);
         }
        }
    }
```

This is my Helper Class

```
public class BaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public BaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Employees.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createtable = "create table Employee " + "(Name TEXT, " + "Mobile TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createtable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

This is my Database class. I'm using it for input and data retrieval. It was working fine for input when the `selectEmployees()` method was not there but now it is showing `Null Pointer Exception`.

```
public class Database {

    private BaseHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public Database(Context c){
        helper = new BaseHelper(c); 
    }

    public void input(String Name, String Mobile){
         db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        try{
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Mobile", Mobile);
        values.put("Name", Name);
        db.insert("Employee", "", values);
        Log.e("ENTERED", "ENTERED   "+values);
        }finally {
            if (db != null)
                db.close();
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<EmployeesResult> selectEmployees() {

         db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        try{
        ArrayList<EmployeesResult> results = new ArrayList<EmployeesResult>();
         Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Employee", null);

         if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    results.add(new EmployeesResult(
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"))));
                            //c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Mobile"))));
                }while(c.moveToNext());
         }
        return results;
    }finally {
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
    }
    }
}
```

The `EmployeeResult` class:

```
public class EmployeesResult {
    public EmployeesResult(String Name){
        name = Name;
        //mobile = Mobile;  
    }
    public String name;
    public int mobile;
}
```

This is Logcat

```
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.TabListData/com.TabListData.EmployeesList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at com.TabListData.Database.selectEmployees(Database.java:35)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at com.TabListData.EmployeesList.onCreate(EmployeesList.java:30)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-15 23:44:11.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: There's some very strange things going on with indentation and brackets in your code. You might want to check if the formatting broke when you copied it over here.

Comment: Also, what line is throwing the error?

Comment: Why don't you try creating method in BaseHelper  that will return the database.
 db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToTheDatabase, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); Assuming that the database already exists in your /data/data/<packagename>/databases.
OR use
SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file.getPath(), null); which is equivalent to the previously mentioned way.

Your database is null thats why you have NullPointerException thrown

Comment: I tried creating method in DaseHelper also but the result is same Null pointer Exception I have checked my data base It is not null entries are there which I entered before creating selectEmployees()  I am posting Logcat Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved I found where the problem exactly the problem was in ListActivity and EmployeeResult class

For ListActivity take a XML layout with only text to display text in ListView
Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
android:padding="10dp"    
android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

and in ListActivity you just need to set a ListAdapter

like this in onCreate() method

```
List<String> data = dh.SelectStudent();
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListofStudents.this, R.layout.text, data));
```

and insted of EmployeesResult class take String in ArrayAdapter and List

the method in DataBase class should be

```
public ArrayList<String> SelectStudent() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = _dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Student", null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                results.add(c.getString(1));
               // results.add(c.getString(4));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return results;
    } finally {
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
    }
}
```

I have passed String in List and ArrayAdepter, If u want more then one string like Name and Mobile Number or a combination of String and Image in the item in List View in that case u need to make a separate class in which u have images and string and you need to pass that class instead of String in List and ArrayAdepter.

THANX

Comment: I encountered the same problem as you. But I don't understand your fix. The NullPointerException is throw in `SQLiteDatabase db = _dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`, your didn't change this line, but why it's fixed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error may be caused by an null-pointer in Context

```
public class SqLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public SqLite(Context context, String table, boolean readOnly) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        getReadableDatabase();
```